# Manipulating an integer in python

Tags: python

An integer like:

```
number = 1873
```

I have a formula: weighted_sum = 1*1 + 8*2 + 7*3 + 3*4 = 50. I want to calculate weighted sum of four digits, so output looks like:

```
1234 weighted sum: 30 / 4321 weighted sum:20
```

I tried to convert integer to string, but did't work.

```
number = str(1742)
weighted = number[0]*1 + number[1]*2 + number[2]*3 + number[3]*4
print(number, "weighted sum:", weighted)
```

Output

```
1742 Weight Sum: 1774442222
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the individual digits back to integer before multipyling them:

```
weighted = int(number[0])*1 + int(number[1])*2 + int(number[2])*3 + int(number[3])*4
```

Just taking `number[i]` will give you a single-character string with of that digit, and multiplying a string bt `n` in Python means concatenating it `n` times.

This can be simplified using `sum()` and a generator expression:

```
weighted = sum(i * int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(number, 1))
```

Comment: How to do achieve this without using string?

Comment: @Kee You need to perform the conversion to the decimal system manually to do this without using a string, i.e. divide by ten in a loop and store the sequence of remainders.

Comment: @SvenMarnach. You first `weighted` does not work properly. Not `number[3]` and `number[4]` . These will be `number[2]` and `number[3]` respectively.

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque Yeah, I just copied that from the question and didn't realize the indices were wrong.  I only checked the first two. :)

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to do it using string you have to do this kind of thing (If i use your logic)

```
number = str(1742)
weighted = int(number[0])*1 + int(number[1])*2 + int(number[2])*3 + int(number[3])*4
print(number, "weighted sum:", weighted)
```

In fact in python if you multiply a string by an int it repete it multiple time. For example

```
>>>"a" * 3
"aaa"
>>>"foo" * 2 
"foofoo"
```

One smaller way to do it is using a list comprehension

```
number = 1742
sum([i * int(nb) for i,nb in enumerate(str(number))])
```

One ugly way to do it without string as asked is

```
number = 1742
weighted = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    temp = number // 10 ** (4-i)
    weighted += i * temp
    number -= temp * 10 ** (4-i)
```

I tried to do a time analysis using `timeit.timeit` and we get

- My first answer (without loop)

  `>>> timeit.timeit(..., number = 1000000)
  1.3271157014933124`
- For the answer of Sven Marnach using generator

  `>>>timeit.timeit("sum(i * int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(str(1742),1))", number = 1000000)
  2.0325663901261066`
- For my answer using list comprehension

  `>>> timeit.timeit("sum([i * int(nb) for i,nb in enumerate(str(1742))])", number = 1000000)
  1.918556083665976`
- For my answer without any string

  `timeit.timeit("number = 1742 ....)
  2.8422619991572446`
- For ikku answer without any string

  `>>>timeit.timeit(..., number = 1000000)
   1.2137944809691135`

So it seems that here **the faster** that I tested **with string and loop is a list comprehension**.

**the faster** that I tested **with string is the first answer** I gave.

**The faster** that I tested **is Ikku answer**

Comment: You first weighted does not work properly. Not `number[3]` and `number[4]` . These will be `number[2]` and `number[3]` respectively.

Comment: Yeah sorry you're right i just copied and pasted the question and didn't saw that ;) ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

your approach would have worked fine, except that a string multiplied by number `n` is a concatenation of `n` times that string in python, so `"7"*2` becomes the string `"77"`, not the number `14`

You want actual integer multiplication and as such have to change this line:

```
weighted = number[0]*1 + number[1]*2 + number[2]*3 + number[3]*4
```

to this:

```
weighted = int(number[0])*1 + int(number[1])*2 + int(number[2])*3 + int(number[3])*4
```

Whether the conversion to and from string is very efficient is a different question, but it should work.

Comment: You weighted does not work properly. Not `number[3]` and `number[4]` . These will be `number[2]` and `number[3]` respectively. –

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it without using strings:

```
import math

number = 1873
answer = 0
length = math.ceil(math.log10(number))

while length > 0:
    current_digit = number % 10
    answer += current_digit * length
    number = number // 10
    length -= 1

print(answer)
```

Here I use `log10` and `ceil` to calculate the number of digits in `number`. Then we loop through all numbers from right to left. We get the `current_digit`, calculate the current value and add it to `answer`. At the end of the loop we update `number` by removing the last digit (dividing by 10) and decrease the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be this one:

```
dlist=[]
number=1234

while number:
    digit = number % 10
    dlist += [digit]
    number //= 10

print(sum([a*b for a,b in zip(dlist, range(len(dlist),0,-1))]))
```

To briefly explain it:
You get all digits of the number and store it to a list.

```
dlist = [4][3][2][1]
```

Then you take another list
Then, within the zip-command we create another list starting from leng-of-your-dlist to 1 (steps -1):

```
[4][3][2][1]
```

Then we multiply each element of dlist with the newly generated list.

Finally, the `sum` command calculates the sum of it

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work properly because of this line `weighted = number[0]*1 + number[1]*2 + number[3]*3 + number[4]*4`. So, instead of this line use following line :

```
weighted = int(number[0])*1 + int(number[1])*2 + int(number[2])*3 + int(number[3])*4
```

And your full code will be like this :

```
number = str(1742)
weighted = int(number[0])*1 + int(number[1])*2 + int(number[2])*3 + int(number[3])*4
print(number, "weighted sum:", weighted)
```

Output :

```
1742 weighted sum: 35
```

**And**

```
number = str(1742)
weighted = (number[0])*1 + (number[1])*2 + (number[2])*3 + (number[3])*4
print(number, "weighted sum:", weighted)
```

Output :

```
1742 weighted sum: 1774442222
```